# Why flashdata in CodeIgniter does not always work whereas userdata always works?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have one code block for assigning some values to `flashdata` in `report` controller and another block for accessing `flashdata` in `export_data` controller.

`Report` Controller:

```
if ($this->input->get_post('date_frm')) {
              $conditions[] = 'appointment_date >= "'.trim($this->input->get_post('date_frm', TRUE)).'"';
            }

            if ($this->input->get_post('date_to')) {
              $conditions[] = 'appointment_date <= "'.trim($this->input->get_post('date_to', TRUE)).'"';
            }

            $conditions = $this->search_model->searchterm_handler($conditions);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('ext_data', $conditions);
```

And in `Export_data` Controller:

```
$myVar = $this->session->flashdata('ext_data');
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('ext_data');
```

It does not always work, but when I use `userdata` rather than `flashdata` it is working fine. Why?

Comment: **What exactly does *"not always work"* and *"working fine"* mean?**

Comment: @Sparky : "not always work" means when I execute this program on my machine then flashdata is working and when deployed to the server it stops working and also when I merge my code to another developer machine working on same project it also stops working

Comment: Don't you think that's important enough to have explained within your OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **OP**:  when I use `userdata` rather than `flashdata` it is working fine

Data set with `flashdata()` is only saved for a ***one-time*** request, then cleared out:

> [Documentation:](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)  *CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.*

...and `keep_flashdata()` only saves the data for **one additional** request after the first:

> [Documentation:](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)  *If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an additional request, you can do so using the `keep_flashdata()` method.*

---

However, `userdata()` is always available until the session is destroyed.

See:  [**What is Session Data?**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#what-is-session-data)

---

I think you should read the full documentation:  [**Session Library**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

First You Should Know what is [flashdata](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata).

It does not clear session value when it is called.Even it is available for next server call and will not be available for 2nd call.

As an example suppose you have two function in a controller

```
function test1()
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('ext_data', 'test');
}
function test2()
{
    echo $this->session->userdata('ext_data');
    echo $this->session->userdata('ext_data');
    echo $this->session->userdata('ext_data');
}
```

Now if you call `your_site_url/controller/test1` it will set `test` for `ext_data`

After that if you call `your_site_url/controller/test2` it will print `test` word 3 times means you can use this session variable for this time as much you want but for next call(hit again `your_site_url/controller/test2`) it will be blank.

Hope you understand what does it mean.

> CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be
>   available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.

Comment: I think in test2() you have missed flashdata but you wrote userdata, it is confusing